# Rinkeby: waiting for transaction to be mined

Tags: transactions, pending-transactions, rinkeby, faucets

My transactions (publishing contracts and sending ether) aren't going through on Rinkeby (last several hours). Metamask is listing those txs as failed.

I've set my gas price fairly high (100+) with no results.

Why is this, and what is the prognosis?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it may have to do with a bug in Metamask:

https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/6vola9/metamask_errors/

Answer (score 0):

You should probably try to write a deploy script using `ethers.js` instead of Metamask. You would have to find a Json RPC Provider, the most common ones are Infura and Moralis.

You can find additional info about that way in this brilliant FreeCodeCamp solidity [course](https://youtu.be/gyMwXuJrbJQ?t=28672) (video timestamp attached).